# jquery disable button only works IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app, this jquery button group is generated with c#

```
<ul class="ui-grid-d">
    <li class="ui-block-a"><a id="MostrarDetallePedido" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a" disabled="disabled" href="/Documentos/Docs/DocsDetalle?StrIdDocumento=01500___00000000000000041" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Detalle</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-block-b"><a id="ItemCondiciones" class="ui-state-disabled ui-btn ui-btn-up-b" disabled="disabled" href="/Documentos/Docs/DocsDetalle?StrIdDocumento=01500___00000000000000041" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-ajax="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Condiciones</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-block-c"><a id="ItemEliminar" class="ui-state-disabled ui-btn ui-btn-up-c" disabled="disabled" href="/Documentos/Docs/DocsDetalle?StrIdDocumento=01500___00000000000000041" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-ajax="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Eliminar</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-block-d"><a id="ItemAdiciones" class="ui-state-disabled ui-btn ui-btn-up-d" disabled="disabled" href="/Documentos/Docs/DocsDetalle?StrIdDocumento=01500___00000000000000041" data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-ajax="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Adiciones</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-block-e"><a id="ItemComponentes" class="ui-state-disabled ui-btn ui-btn-up-e" disabled="disabled" href="/Documentos/Docs/DocsDetalle?StrIdDocumento=01500___00000000000000041" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-ajax="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Componentes</span></span></a></li> 
</ul>
```

Then i have a jquery func that enable or disable some buttons:

```
    function (data) {
        $(data).find('error').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == 'NoError') {
                $('#ItemEliminar').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#MostrarDetallePedido').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ItemComponentes').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ItemAdiciones').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ItemCondiciones').prop('disabled', false);

                $(data).find('NombreItem').each(function () {
                    $('#NombreItem').text($(this).text());
                })
                $(data).find('OpcionesItem').each(function () {
                    alert($(this).text());
                })

            } else {
                $(data).find('NombreItem').each(function () {
                    $('#NombreItem').text($(this).text());
                })
                $('#ItemEliminar').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#MostrarDetallePedido').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ItemComponentes').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#ItemAdiciones').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#ItemCondiciones').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })
    }
```

This function works great but the problem is that it only works on IE. Crhrome and firefox never disable de jquery button.

Comment: Only form elements have `disabled` property. Note that `.find('error')` finds nothing, if `error` is a class name it should be `find('.error')`.

Comment: Really i don't have a form, just a group of buttons that interact with some images. That buttons are really **a** tags.

Comment: They are not actually buttons, they are anchor links and you cannot disable them.

Comment: error is a node of an xml. As i say it works great in IE. Ok it means  I must to convert the group buttom to a form with that buttons?

Comment: No need to use input type button, anchor type will work also. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery UI buttons, use the api's methods  http://api.jqueryui.com/button/

```
$('#ItemEliminar')
     .button('disable') // disable the button
     .button('refresh'); // refresh it's state
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adjusting the property, which doesn't exist for <a>, you should add the ui-disabled class to the item.
So instead of:

```
$('#ItemEliminar').prop('disabled', true);
```

Use `$('#ItemEliminar').toggleClass('ui-disabled');`

or if you want more control:

`$('#ItemEliminar').addClass('ui-disabled');` to disable it

and

`$('#ItemEliminar').removeClass('ui-disabled');` to enable it.

> Sugessted edit from @s.Daniel:
>
> > Also you should consider replacing `<error>`with `<div class="error">`
> >     or `<div id="error">` to do things in a standard way avoiding
> >     problems.

Thank you for the suggestion, but as I understand data is some kind of array with data into it, and not an DOM element that contains the data

Comment: Just one thing why it receive the click and navigate to the propper anchor? even it has ui-disabled?

Comment: Hmmm... That's strange... it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9386M/1/   I'm guessing the problem is in some other part of the script

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.8.11 it is the default for MVC4 you are using 1.8.2 it must be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably have to use css:

I got this here a while back:

```
a[disabled="disabled"] { 
set your opacity, etc here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The aproach of **wirey**, solve part of the problem but it throw a message, indicating that the button disable option must be initialized.

Modifing **wirey** code works for me.

```
$('#ItemEliminar')
   .button({ disabled: false }) //Here initializes disable option
   .button('disable')           // Disable the button
   .button('refresh');          // Refresh
```